# Correlation of time series with auto-correlation

Tags: time-series, correlation, autocorrelation

When we calculate the variance of a auto-correlated time series, we need to do some shrinkage to get the correct value.
What about say we have two time series, X, Y. Each has auto-correlation. Will that effect the correlation Cor(X, Y)? What about the Cov(X, Y)? What kind of adjustment is needed?